# Edit validation rules that refer to another workbook

Tags: excel

I have a master workbook with several rows and columns some of which have validation rules referring to the same workbook.

I want to select subsets of this, copy them to another set of workbooks and distribute them to several users.

The trouble is that the validation rules refer back to the master workbook and the users won't have access to this so are unable to edit the data in the cells affected.

A typical validation rule (in the copy of the original workbook) looks like

```
=[All.xlsx]Lookup!C2:C3
```

Is there any automated way to remove the [All.xlsx] ? I'm just doing it manually at present.

Answer (score 0):

Find replace has always worked well for me.
Ctrl+H
Find: [All.xlsx]
Replace:              *leave blank*